# Excel Transfer Utility installation issue

Tags: sitecore-client, installation, sitecore-marketplace

I tried to install "**Excel Transfer Utility**" package in Sitecore 8.1 instance but it's continuously spinning only and doesn't install.

Does this utility is not compatible with Sitecore 8.1?

https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Excel_Transfer_Utility.aspx

thanks

Comment: any log entries ?

Comment: ERROR Unable to connect to server localhost:27017: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:27017.

Comment: Does sitecore analytics also needs to be enabled for this utlity

Comment: I saw few times packages are not installed if Analytics is enabled and Mongo is not running.

Comment: ok so Should I disable analytics and if yes how because I'm using sitecore 8.1 version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the installation is not working is because mongoDB is not present. By default, when Sitecore is installed, the connection string of the mongoDB is already available in the `ConnectionStrings.config` file and Sitecore Analytics is enabled.

Due to this, when Sitecore runs, it will try to connect to the MongoDB. This is the reason why the installation may takes lot of time to complete or having the *never end installation* issue like the one your are experiencing. You will have the same issue with other package installation.

So, as you already mention, disabling the Analytics will fix the problem. Though, instead of changing the Sitecore config file directly, it is recommended to patch the setting as follows:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <settings>
      <setting name="Xdb.Enabled" value="false" />
    </settings>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

and name the file as `z.DisableSitecoreAnalytics.config` so that it overrides the Sitecore configuration file. This will prevent any issues tomorrow when upgrading the Sitecore Version as it may overwritten the Sitecore Analytics config file when performing an upgrade.

However, if you do not intend to make use of the MongoDB at all, it is preferable to remove the connection string of the MongoDB.

**Update**

Sitecore will make use of both mongoDB analytics and the Sitecore analytics DB. What happens is that data are captured and store in mongoDB then when session is expired ( default is 20mins), Sitecore flushes the data from MongoDB to the Sitecore Analytics DB. The results can be viewed from the experience analytics

Comment: yeah got it and other option is to install MongoDB on system without disabling SitecoreAnalytics because finally I need SitecoreAnalytics enabled to see Goal creation reports generation.

But here I'm not sure when we enable SitecoreAnalytics Does sitecore use Sitecore_Analytics DB for report ( which installed with default sitecore instance installation )
OR
MongoDB ( `<add name="analytics" connectionString="mongodb://localhost/analytics" />` )

Comment: @Sukhi please see updated answer

Comment: right now I installed MogoDB on my system and didn't disable Xdb.Enabled setting. I'm able to install Utility package quickly finally looks like to install this module we must have MongoDB installed on system.

Comment: Not only this module. Any Sitecore Package installation would have take time or never ends if you have xDB enable but not MongoDB

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Mongo DB installed on my system so I did following settings

```
<setting name="Xdb.Enabled" value="false" />
```

and it's worked out for me...